# How can I display the table footer at the bottom when converting an HTML table to PDF?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core-webapi, aspose.words

I want to change HTML page to pdf,that convertion is going to be fine but when the html code having the tables then the conversion is going to display thead, tfoot and tbody

Here we are using the code like

```
public ActionResult WorkflowHTMLtoPDF()
    {
        var JResult = new JsonResult();
        try
        {
            string HTMLContent =@"<html><head><meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8"><meta name="documentId" content="f29aeed2-da65-4043-8355-c302a71c2d10"><meta name="documentSetId" content="d12625b1-2af9-4532-af91-d40b65eeffef"><meta name="documentVersionNumber" content="16"><meta name="documentEffectiveTime" content="20230810"><title>These highlights do not include all the information needed to use CELECOXIB CAPSULES safely and effectively. See full prescribing information for CELECOXIB CAPSULES.CELECOXIB capsules, for oral useInitial U.S. Approval: 1998kjj</title><link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://www.accessdata.fda.gov/spl/stylesheet/spl.css"><script src="http://www.accessdata.fda.gov/spl/stylesheet/spl.js" type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">/* */</script></head><body class="spl" id="spl" onload="if(typeof convertToTwoColumns == &quot;function&quot;)convertToTwoColumns();" data-new-gr-c-s-check-loaded="14.1007.0" data-gr-ext-installed="">
```

Table 1. Recommended Dosage of Abacavir, Dolutegravir and Lamivudine Tablets for Oral Suspension in Pediatric Patients 
                  
                  
                  
                  
                    
                      
                        
                          <sup>a</sup>Abacavir, dolutegravir and lamivudine tablet for oral suspension is a fixed-dose combination product containing 60 mg of abacavir, 5 mg of dolutegravir, and 30 mg of lamivudine.
                      
                    
                  
                  
                    
                      
                         Body Weight
                        
                      
                      
                         Abacavir, Dolutegravir and Lamivudine Tablets for Oral Suspension<sup>a</sup>
                        
                         Number of Tablets
                        
                      
                      
                         Total Daily Dose
                        
                      
                    
                    
                      
                         10 kg to <14 kg
                        
                      
                       4 tablets once daily
                       240 mg abacavir, 20 mg dolutegravir, and 120 mg lamivudine once daily
                    
                    
                      
                         14 kg to <20 kg
                        
                      
                       5 tablets once daily
                       300 mg abacavir, 25 mg dolutegravir, and 150 mg lamivudine once daily
                    
                    
                      
                         20 kg to <25 kg
                        
                      
                       6 tablets once daily
                       360 mg abacavir, 30 mg dolutegravir, and 180 mg lamivudine once daily
                    
                    
                      
                         ≥25 kg
                        
                      
                       Not recommended
                       600 mg of abacavir, 50 mg of dolutegravir, and 300 mg of lamivudine
                    
                  
                ";

```
            HTMLContent = HTMLContent.Replace("class=\"Sub\">", "class=\"Sub\"><sub>");
            HTMLContent = HTMLContent.Replace("<div></div>", "");
            HTMLContent = HTMLContent.Replace("class=\"Sup\">", "class=\"Sup\"><sup>").Replace("<a href=\"javascript:toggleMixin();\">Document Id: </a>", "<span>Document Id: </span>");
                            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(HTMLContent))
            {
                                        string strCompleteHTMLContent = HTMLContent;
                    strCompleteHTMLContent = RearrangeTable(strCompleteHTMLContent);
                    string strFileNameGuid = SetID + ".html";

                    System.IO.File.WriteAllText(Server.MapPath("~/PDFViewer/web/" + SPLDevelopmentID + "/" + strFileNameGuid), strCompleteHTMLContent, System.Text.Encoding.UTF8);

                    //Saving the pdf file
                    var pathToCreate = Server.MapPath("~/PDFViewer/web/" + SPLDevelopmentID + "/" + SetID + ".pdf");

                    var pathToCreatehtml = Server.MapPath("~/PDFViewer/web/" + SPLDevelopmentID + "/" + strFileNameGuid);

                    Aspose.Words.License lic = new Aspose.Words.License();
                    lic.SetLicense("Aspose.Words.lic");
                    Aspose.Words.LoadOptions ldOptions = new Aspose.Words.LoadOptions();
                    ldOptions.Encoding = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8;
                    ldOptions.LoadFormat = Aspose.Words.LoadFormat.Doc;
                    Aspose.Words.Document doc = new Aspose.Words.Document(pathToCreatehtml, ldOptions);

                    // Render first page of Word document to an image stream
                    //Aspose.Words.Saving.ImageSaveOptions options = new Aspose.Words.Saving.ImageSaveOptions(Aspose.Words.SaveFormat.Jpeg);
                    //options.PageIndex = 0;
                    //options.PageCount = 1;

                    foreach (Section section in doc.Sections)
                    {
                        section.PageSetup.PaperSize = Aspose.Words.PaperSize.A4;
                    }
                    doc.UpdatePageLayout();
              
                        doc.ExpandTableStylesToDirectFormatting();
                    doc.Save(pathToCreate, Aspose.Words.SaveFormat.Pdf);       
                
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
         
        }
        return JResult;
    }
```

In **RearrangeTable** method

```
static string RearrangeTable(string html)
    {
        var doc = new HtmlDocument();
        doc.LoadHtml(html);

        var tables = doc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//table");

        if (tables != null)
        {
            foreach (var tableNode in tables)
            {
                // Find thead, tbody, and tfoot elements within the current table
                var thead = tableNode.SelectSingleNode(".//thead");
                var tbody = tableNode.SelectSingleNode(".//tbody");
                var tfoot = tableNode.SelectSingleNode(".//tfoot");

                // Remove existing thead, tbody, and tfoot elements
                tableNode.ChildNodes.ToList().ForEach(childNode => childNode.Remove());

                // Add elements in the desired order: thead, tbody, tbody, tfoot
                if (thead != null) tableNode.AppendChild(thead);
                if (tbody != null) tableNode.AppendChild(tbody);
                if (tbody != null) tableNode.AppendChild(tbody.Clone());
                if (tfoot != null) tableNode.AppendChild(tfoot);
            }
        }

        return doc.DocumentNode.OuterHtml;
    }
```

Comment: The problem with `tfoot` is logged as **WORDSNET-25805**.  Currently, Aspose.Words inserts a content of `tfoot` immediately as the first row of the table. As a workaround you can avoid using `tfoot` and `thead` and use regular table rows in the required order.